# SAS put data to Excel via DDE

Tags: excel, sas, dde

I want to write some data to Excel via DDE and have the following code:

```
option noxwait noxsync;
x call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE";

%let delay=5;
data _null_;
    rc=sleep(&delay); 
run;

filename random dde 'excel|Tabelle1!r1c1:r100c3';
data _null_;
    set sashelp.class;
    file random;
    put name sex age;
run;
```

Excel opens successfully however the sheet remains empty. The log tells me that 19 records were written to the file RANDOM.

Any suggestions why the data is not written to my Excel sheet? Could it be connected with my language settings (German) in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried adding a 5-second delay between opening excel and running your data step?

Comment: Yes, please find my edit in my question.

Comment: I would reconsider the use of DDE at all.  Try using `ods excel` instead, especially if you're simply dumping a table to a new worksheet.

Comment: @RobertPenridge: This suits not with my requirements. I have an Excel template file and want to add some data. In other cases you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very mad story from my end: When I changed my language settings from German to English it works fine with the shown code.

Update:
It also works with German language settings, however I have to translate all statements, e.g. the range written to:

English Excel

```
filename random dde 'excel|Sheet1!r1c1:r100c3';
```

German Excel use z(eile) and s(palte) instead of r(ow) and c(olumn)

```
filename random dde 'excel|Tabelle1!z1s1:z100s3';
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  You might want to talk to other German developers to see if there are specific things to make it so that it works in German - it's possible if not likely that there are just small differences (perhaps even not using `Tabelle` but `Sheet` even when running in German?).

Comment: What happens if you work with a file that already exists and has your German names? I suspect it'll work then as well.

Answer (score 2):

`NOXSYNC` is a mistake here.

Basically, what happens when I run this at least is it won't work if `NOXSYNC` is set, because it tries to write to the excel sheet before Excel is ready for it.  You need `XSYNC` to have SAS wait for the `X` command to complete.

If `XSYNC` is something you can't deal with, then you will need to add a manual delay.

I'd also verify that you don't have Excel open before running this, as if you do it may be writing to a different Excel workbook than the one it's opening.

Comment: Thanks for all hints, however nothing solved my issue. I tried, `xsync` and delay and always no Excel instance is open when I start the code. I saw a similar code at my colleagues pc working. But we cannot find the problem with mine.

Comment: @zuluk Does the x-window stay open on your machine?

Comment: Yes, with `noxsync`.No with `xsync`.

Comment: What if you run it twice without doing anything else?  Does the first session get written to?  (It does for me when I don't have `xsync` or a delay.)

Comment: I have to correct: Starting with `xsync` and 5 seconds delay leads into a hanging session. It says "X-command is active."
Running the program twice with `noxsync` leads into 2 empty Excel files and sheets. Same without delay.